# The refactoring option is gone after dart last update, what can I do, I tried restarting and uninstalled Visual Studio Code but nothing happened

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

Click on the image description.

Comment: it will be helpful if you instead of putting image put code here in code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run flutter doctor, if flutter and dart are up to date then try switching to a different flutter channel and update flutter and dart again. It worked for me recently.
**Try switch to `dev` channel**,

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me on beta as well. It's a bit less cutting edge than dev so might be better for some uses.

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
```

Also found out that turning off the `previewLSP` setting in the VSCode Dart & Flutter extension settings turns the refactoring menu back on. There seems to be a disagreement between LSP mode and refactoring that is fixed in later versions. If you don't want to upgrade you can try turning that setting off and then restarting VSCode.

Comment: I originally went from beta to stable and that is when I got the issue. Thanks, the previewLSP option fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I sugest to re-install the flutter plugin for VSCode (wich includes dart). See if it helps.